# installing fax modem drivers on linux

Tags: linux, installation, drivers, modem

EDIT 2:
My modem is of type "HSFModem" so I got to the http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/oem/downloads.php and there I downloaded the debian file. I extracted it, and executed the command dpkg -i hsfmodem_7.80.02.06oem_i386.deb
Installation began, and here is what it said:

```
root@asaosig-desktop:/home/asa-osig# dpkg -i hsfmodem_7.80.02.06oem_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package hsfmodem.
(Reading database ... 289449 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking hsfmodem (from hsfmodem_7.80.02.06oem_i386.deb) ...
Setting up hsfmodem (7.80.02.06oem) ...
Conexant HSF softmodem driver, version 7.80.02.06oem

If you need assistance or more information, please go to:
http://www.linuxant.com/

When reporting a problem for the first time, please send
us the file generated by "hsfconfig --dumpdiag".

No pre-built modules for: Ubuntu-12.04.4 linux-3.5.0-52-generic i686-SMP

Trying to automatically build the driver modules...
(this requires a C compiler and proper kernel sources to be installed)

Building modules for kernel 3.5.0-52-generic, using source directory
/lib/modules/3.5.0-52-generic/build. Please wait...

ERROR: Module build failed!
Please examine the log file "/etc/hsfmodem/log/buildlog-20140715093736.txt" to     determine why.
```

Here is the only error from logfile:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/hsfmodem/modules/mod_engine.c:9:0:
/usr/lib/hsfmodem/modules/GPL/oscompat.h:125:24: fatal error: asm/system.h: No such   file or directory
```

It seems that the file asm/system.h which is missing creates my problems. Can I find it and download it from somewhere?

edit 1:
I installed the rpm package with the alien command, and the process was finished without errors. But my fax still does not work. Efax-gtk application always shows "inactive" message.
I am trying to install USB 2.0 fax modem on my linux xubuntu machine.
I am following the instructions and I entered:
rpm -i dgcmodem-1.13-1.i386.rpm

After that,I got this error:

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
warning: dgcmodem-1.13-1.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5dfbf7dc: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    pciutils is needed by dgcmodem-1.13-1.i386
    gcc is needed by dgcmodem-1.13-1.i386
    /bin/sh is needed by dgcmodem-1.13-1.i386
root@asaosig-desktop:/home/asa-osig#
```

Answer (score 0):

> rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
>
> rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...

You are trying to install a RPM package on Ubuntu. Using rpm.

You should use Alien instead. (As the warning - that you have ignored - suggests.)

```
sudo alien --to-deb -i <your package name.rpm>
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I did it through the alien command as you recommended, and it said that installation went fine. But my fax still does not work and efax-gtk is "inactive".

Comment: Note that the package you are trying to install is aimed at the i386 architecture, whereas the Pi has an ARM architecture processor. Given, that no ARM binaries are distributed, you best choice would be to compile the source code on the Pi.